# Spring Security SAML autologin for user in domain

Tags: spring, spring-security, saml-2.0, adfs2.0, spring-saml

I've got application with spring security SAML filters. There is configuration with ADFS 2.0. Server is standing on machine out of domain. I try to login on my App on domain account of user (but window to input domain user principals is displayed). Is there possibility to config this to autologin for user on which domain user we're logged on windows?

Thanks a log.

Comment: So in other words you would like that ADFS doesn't display window asking for principals, but instead automatically authenticates the user, and returns back to your App, is that correct?

Comment: I guess Spring SAML extention has to be configured to specify authcontext 'urn:federation:authentication:windows' in the SAML authentication request

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh599318.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can configure custom `authnContext` sent in your SAML request by changing bean `samlEntryPoint` in the following way:

```
<bean id="samlEntryPoint" class="org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLEntryPoint">
    <property name="defaultProfileOptions">
        <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileOptions">
            <property name="authnContexts"
                      value="urn:federation:authentication:windows"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```